# Onesignal, Ionic App : Open specific view when click on notification not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

Ive created an hybrid android app based on Ionic, Using Onesignal i'm sending notifications to the application, its working good, the user app recieve the notification and when i click on it, it open the app home view.

What im trying to do is to open a specific page when users click on the notifications.

Based on the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk), here is what i did :

My app.js file :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova', 'starter.controllers', 'ui.router' ])

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup,$cordovaSplashscreen,$state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        // Enable to debug issues.
        // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

        var notificationOpenedCallback = function(result) {
            //var data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

                var state = $injector.get($state);
                state.go('#/app/post/49726');
        };

        window.plugins.OneSignal.init("********-****-****-****-***********",
                                         {googleProjectNumber: "**************"},
                                         notificationOpenedCallback);

        // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
        window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
    });

})
```

Here is the stateProvider

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: "/home/",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/posts.html",
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.posts', {
            url: "/posts/:categoryId",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/posts.html",
                    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.post', {
            url: "/post/:postId",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/post.html",
                    controller: 'PostCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home/');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fould it by myself, here is the correct code if anyone is struggling with that :

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup,$cordovaSplashscreen,$state,$injector) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        // Enable to debug issues.
        // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

        var notificationOpenedCallback = function(result) {
            $state.go('app.post', { "postId": "49726"});
        };

        window.plugins.OneSignal.init("********-****-****-****-***********",
                                     {googleProjectNumber: "**************"},
                                     notificationOpenedCallback);

        // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
        window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
    });

})
```